# Read from a file not found in the startup project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

My web solution has a number of projects.

- The startup project is called: "Bob"
- "Bob" has a reference to "Gill" project.
- Inside "Gill", there is a file inside that i want to read. "Gill/One/Two/hi.txt"

I have some code in Bob, that calls some code inside the "Gill" project that tries to access the above txt file:

```
File.ReadAllText(@"~/One/Two/hi.txt")
```

That does not find the file.

---

I have marked the file build as

> Content

I have marked Copy to Output Directory as:

> Copy if newer

**What's the approach to getting access to the file?**

Comment: To get access to the file you need to copy it to the startup projects executable directory or store a path in your config that points to the directory the file is in. Alternatively you can embed it as a resource and access it that way. All your startup project needs is a reference to the DLL that the other project outputs so it won't see additional content files. "Copy if newer" just copies into a directory relative to the current project. I've had solutions before that have a dedicated "resources" project whose job was to publish the assets to the right place

Comment: @Charleh this gives me access to the dll. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() ` now what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've set the file to Copy To Output Directory, this will be in the bin directory of your application.

Changing Igor answer slightly, you could do

```
var root = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bin");
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, "One", "Two", "hi.txt");
if(System.IO.File.Exists(filePath)) {
    var allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
}
```

Which will resolve the `bin` directory for your application, where your file will be rooted.

Answer (score 1):

try file path as

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin\\One\\Two\\hi.txt");
```

And set 
Build Action: none

Copy to output: Copy always (or copy if newer)

Comment: "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\One\\Two\\hi.txt'."

Comment: i made an update jimmy, it was becasue of the slash at the beginning i think.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `~` is used by .NET webform and only be allowed by `Server.MapPath` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx)

You could get the File by `new System.IO.FileInfo(@"One/Two/hi.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. Make sure the file has been copied to your web site. You cant read from it if it does not exist.
2. Put together the file path correctly. The executing code does not directly know about `~` as a path character, you have to translate that into a root path of the website for any types in the `System.IO` namespace like `File` or `Path`. The best way to do that is to use [HostingEnvironment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment(v=vs.110).aspx).

Code:

```
var root = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~");
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, "One", "Two", "hi.txt");
if(System.IO.File.Exists(filePath)) {
    var allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
}
```

Files marked as Content and Copied referenced in outside projects (that are in turn referenced by the web project) will have their content copied relative to the `bin` folder of the web application. In this case add `bin` to the root path like so:

```
var root = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bin");
```

Comment: This code is trying to look inside the "Bob" directory (startup project) rather than the "Gill" directory (The project where the file is placed)

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 - Everything is relative to the root web application. So if you have a file in a different project that you want to include it should be included relative to the publish path (web app). Build your path from that point as the web application has no concept of projects (Gill / Bob) a solution which is a pure Visual Studio concept.

Comment: I understand this, however, i'd like the file to exist in my project. That's why my question is asking how to get the file accessible when running the application. I thought copy to output was supposed to assist in this. Putting it into the output directory should allow you to get hold of the file.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 - When you include content from external projects from the web applicatino project they will be placed relative to the startup projects `bin` folder. So `Bob\bin\Gill\relativeFilePath`. That `relativeFilePath` depends on the additional folders you had specified. This is not a very handy construct and usually static content to be included in the project (like .txt, .xls, .mdb, etc files) are referenced in the web application project directly.

Comment: if you put `~/bin`, it works. Thanks for almost getting me there, edit your answer and i'll accept :)

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 - glad to help.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 - ah, I see someone copied/pasted my answer and beat me to it?